# FCM response, "NotRegistered" after the first message

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I did all settings what is mentioned in `FCM` site, and I got token id as well. But while sending from messages from `FCM` Console or calling the rest `api` using server key, I am getting error after first message.

here is the response,

```
{
"multicast_id":8241908730600726000,
"success": 0,
"failure": 1,
"canonical_ids": 0,
"results": [
  {
     "error": "NotRegistered"
  }
],
}
```

The first message is not giving error, but even that first message is not delivering. and after on every message sent, I am getting this error. "NotRegistered"

Comment: Is there any solution about this problem? I have same problem